# Increase speed of function that reads a string

Tags: python, performance

I'm trying to learn how to increase the speed of my code. This function is supposed to read a really long string and it seems to be a bit on the slow side. The input is a string which sholud be read and return a list depending on the "level" it is placed. I'm wondering if there is a way for me to increase the speed of my code below:

````
def readexpr1(q):  # q=[[16,[[4,4],4]],[[32,[4,16]],64]]```  
    y = []
    lvl = 0
    s = ""
    for n in q:
        # print(y, "-")
        if n == "[":
            lvl += 1
            if s:
                y.append(int(s)*(2**(lvl)))
            s = ""
        elif n == "]":
            lvl -= 1
            if s:
                y.append(int(s)*(2**(lvl)))
            s = ""
        elif n == ",":
            if s:
                y.append(int(s)*(2**(lvl)))
            s = ""
        else:
            s = "".join([s, n])
    return y```
````

Comment: try `ast.literal_eval('[[16,[[4,4],4]],[[32,[4,16]],64]]')` after `import ast`

Comment: For the provided input `"[[16,[[4,4],4]],[[32,[4,16]],64]]"` the original implementation returns `[32, 16, 128, 128]`. Is it what's expected?

Comment: Yes, it is! In the next step I count the duplicates. But that part does not take as much time as this function. " @dlask

Comment: So your function only takes the last value of each nested list, multiplies it by `2**lvl` and makes this value a part of the output list, right?

Comment: No, I'm sorry, I misread your first comment. The output is ```[64, 64, 32, 32, 256, 64, 128, 32]```. @dlask

Comment: No, it it not. I have just executed your script with your input string. The result is what I've shown above. Perhaps it would be useful to describe the expected function behavour, or to provide a working reference implementation.

Comment: I'm stupid, I forgot a few rows. I've edited the code now. @dlask, I'm sorry

Comment: Is it intentional to have all list items multiplied by `2**N` but the last list item multiplied by `2**(N-1)`, where `N` is the current nesting level?

Comment: What do you mean by "read" a string? If you already have a string, the job is done - "reading" normally means that you get data from an outside source, such as a file or a web site, and create something in your program that represents the raw data. If you are trying to take raw data that you *already have* and *interpret it* as representing something more complex, that is called *parsing*. (I am not being pedantic; I am helping you use a search engine. If you use words properly, it will be easier to do your own research.)

Comment: What output do you expect and what's going wrong? Please improve the question.

Answer (score 0):

Provided that each value has to be multiplied by `2**L` where `L` is the nesting level, the following code makes the required conversion.

```py
import ast


def collect(l, level):
    """Collect multiplied values from a list at `level`."""
    for x in l:
        if type(x) == list:
            yield from collect(x, level + 1)
        else:
            yield x * 2**level


def readexpr2(q):
    """Convert string to the list of multiplied values."""
    s = ast.literal_eval(q)
    return list(collect(s, 1))


print(readexpr2("[[16,[[4,4],4]],[[32,[4,16]],64]]"))

# Gives [64, 64, 64, 32, 256, 64, 256, 256]
```

Answer (score 0):

I wholeheartedly believe that dlask's solution is the correct solution here, however, a fun idea struck me while thinking about this problem, which I'd like to share.

Warning: this approach is definitely hackier, and it suffers from a huge security concern- `eval()` can and will run any functions you put in there, so if your input list contains malicious values that are actually legit python code, it'd run those too. This is why dlask's solution uses `ast.literal_eval()`- it does not execute functions, and does not suffer from this security problem.

Disclaimers aside, lets get to the code:

```py
def double(nums):
    return (2*x for x in nums)

def read_expr(expr):
    code = "[" + text.replace("]", "])").replace("[", "*double([") + "]"
    return eval(code)
```

As you can see, it does work:

```
>>> expr = "[[16,[[4,4],4]],[[32,[4,16]],64]]"
>>> read_expr(expr)
[64, 64, 64, 32, 256, 64, 256, 256]
```

Now what's going on? With each list, its replacing that list, say for example, `[4, 16]` with the text `*double([4, 16])` which means that it calls `double()` on our list (doubling each element), and then unpacks that into the enclosing list (flattening the nested lists). This happens for every single list (including the outer most one), which is why I had to surround the expression with `[` and `]` explicitly at the end.

Again, this isn't meant to be a good solution that you should copy/paste into production. Its an illustration of another way to view the same problem, using some clever trickery to do less work. For real use, please use dlask's solution.